# Does the flink 1.7.2 dataset not support kafka sink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, flink-batch

Does the flink 1.7.2 dataset not support kafka sink ?

After doing the batch operation I need to publish the message to kafka, meaning source is my postgres and sink is my kafka.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own **output format and use Kafka Producer** to produce to Kafka. Check the code below.

```
...
data.output(new KafkaOPFormat());
env.execute();
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.io.RichOutputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class KafkaOPFormat extends RichOutputFormat<Tuple2<String, String>> {

  private final Properties properties = new Properties();
  private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;

  @Override
  public void configure(Configuration configuration) {
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.put("acks", "all");
    properties.put("retries", 0);
    properties.put("batch.size", 16384);
    properties.put("linger.ms", 1);
    properties.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  }

  @Override
  public void open(int i, int i1) throws IOException {
    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
  }

  @Override
  public void writeRecord(Tuple2<String, String> record) throws IOException {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(record.f0, record.f1));
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    producer.close();
  }
}
```

**PS: I do not remember all the configs, do check for your configuration and alter accordingly.**

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box: not yet, you would have to work with data streams from the beginning onwards or create your own custom output format as mentioned.

There are plans however to unify the `DataSet` and `DataStream` APIs in the Apache Flink project for the long-term in Flink 2.0: https://flink.apache.org/roadmap.html